# Checking the contents of TStringStream

Tags: string, delphi, binary

I have some nice or not so nice data in a `TStringStream` (or it can be any `TStream`), what I would like to visualize in the best way, if it contains text, I would like to display it as a Text, if it's not possible, I would like to display the Hex codes. I understand that there's no **bullet-proof** way of reliably say that's a text or binary, but not that's the goal, just visualize it for debugging proposes.

So if the string

- has only characters `Chars` with codes, between 32 and 127, I can
  accept it as an `AnsiString`. *it's easy implement*
- if not, I would try to convert it to an
  `Utf8String`, as I know `Utf8String` has a *format*, so I could decide is
  it a valid utf8 string or not. So I need some kind of function which can
  tell me yes, it can be an utf8string. if I'm wrong, who cares, if it will be an 
  unreadable text, that's not a problem, I can't read hex codes fluently either.
- if it's still not the case, I would like to interpret it as a widestring, this is the
  hardest part, because as I know It hasn't got any *format*, so I would need to guess a
  lot here, this needs the most creativity. If It's completly a mission impossible, than
  skip this point. but say I'm not expecting Chinese characters.
- else: display the hex codes.

I completely rewrite my question, because everybody was commenting to the fact that, where the data came from, and how should I define a protocol (also I get useful hints, thanks for that), which didn't get me closer to solve my problem, which hopefully is described better in the new question.

Comment: Your binary buffer could contain values in the range 32 to 127. Why don't you decide on a protocol that both sides agree to follow? That's how all communication is performed. Sending blobs of this and that and then guessing what is contained is a recipe for pain. If you want to send text, and need to support Unicode, use UTF8.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I want pain.but really this feature would be mainly just for debuging.in case of raw binary i would print the hex codes...

Comment: I can't understand. You are aware aren't you that text is represented as binary. Everything on a computer is binary.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I'm aware, of course. Maybe I'm not clear enough, I just want to dump the traffic for debugging proposes, I could convert it every time to hex, than I could print example `48656C6C6F`, when there's a `Hello` in my message, but the strings looks much more friendlier isn't it, but when there's not a string on the message, I would print the hex codes, because it's much more sense than a wrongly converted text.

Comment: If you understand that everything on a computer is binary, you'll understand that you cannot reliably distinguish text from other content.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well, I'm sure, I asked my question in a wrong way, I should never mentioned, that the stream is comming from over TCP, everybody is commenting on this, but in my use case it's completly indifferent. However thanks for *Remy Lebeau* i got some useful hints and ideas improving my code, but still this is not related to the question. with *Arioch The* words, there's no bullet-proof validation, I completly agree, also understand your thoughts about *everything is binary*. I don't want to distinguish text from other content reliably too, I just want to visualize it for debugging.

Comment: @balazs: I posted a second answer that addresses your questions about detecting the data encoding.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the answer, That was exactly what I needed. I don't really understand the downvotes, at first maybe the question was misleading, but finally I think It become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if the string
>
> •has only characters Chars with codes, between 32 and 127, I can accept it as an AnsiString. it's easy implement

Yes.  However, character values between 128 and 255 (aka ANSI/MBCS characters) can also be stored in an `AnsiString` and displayed visually, but you have to know the original charset that those values belong to. In the case of D2009+, you can store the values into a `RawByteString` and use the `SetCodePage()` function to associate an appropriate codepage with the string.  That way, the characters are interpretted correctly when you pass the string around your code.  If you don't care about non-ASCII characters outside of Unicode formats, then you can ignore this.

> •if not, I would try to convert it to an Utf8String, as I know Utf8String has a format, so I could decide is it a valid utf8 string or not. So I need some kind of function which can tell me yes, it can be an utf8string.

To check if the data is a valid UTF-8 string, you can use the Win32 API `Windows.MultiByteToWideChar()` function, or Embarcadero's `System.LocaleCharsToUnicode()` function (XE and later only).  Specify the `CP_UTF8` (65001) codepage, the `MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` flag, and a `nil` output buffer.  If the data is a valid UTF-8 string, the function will return the number of UTF-16 characters the data can produce if actually decoded.  Otherwise, the function will fail with an `ERROR_NO_UNICODE_TRANSLATION` error code.

Another option (D2009 and later only) is to use the `GetCharCount()` method of the `SysUtils.TEncoding.UTF8` class to calculate the same number of UTF-16 characters.

> •if it's still not the case, I would like to interpret it as a widestring, this is the hardest part, because as I know It hasn't got any format

Yes, of course it does - UTF-16, which is just as much a defined format as UTF-8 is (in fact, there are two flavors of UTF-16, little endian and big endian).

To check if the data is a valid UTF-16 (little endian only) string, you can use the Win32 API `Windows.WideCharToMultiByte()` function, or Embarcadero's `System.UnicodeToLocaleChars()` function (XE and later only).  Specify the `CP_UTF8` (65001) codepage, the `WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` flag, and a `nil` output buffer.  If the data is a valid UTF-16LE string, the function will return the number of UTF-8 bytes the data can produce if actually encoded.  Otherwise, the function will fail with an `ERROR_NO_UNICODE_TRANSLATION` error code.

Another option (D2009 and later only) is to use the `GetByteCount()` method of the `SysUtils.TEncoding.Unicode` (little endian) or `SysUtils.TEncoding.BigEndianUnicode` class to calculate the same number of UTF-8 bytes.

> so I would need to guess a lot here

No, you don't.  For UTF-8 and UTF-16, there is no guesswork involved.  They are well-defined standardized formats, and they are designed to be converted between each other without any loss of data.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise to define a protocol and stick to it. For example, define that all text is in UTF8, so in Delphi 7 you can use UTF8Encode/UTF8Decode and in XE2 UTF8ToWideString (saves on bandwidth!), and also that each message has a header that defines what it is (for example binary) and how long it is, so you know after the data you can revert to UTF8 for a next message or text.

Comment: `TStringStream` is `TEncoding`-enabled in D2009, so you can use `TStringStream.Create(..., TEncoding.UTF8)` instead of `UTF8ToWideString()`.

Comment: thanks,everybody suggest this which is so true,and I take this advice, but the real question is not that.i'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can not implement bullet-proof validation. Until you have some external restriction what can be passed as string - any character of WideString would also be valid pair of characters in AnsiString. So you would have to pass some marker before the string.

- For unicode string often a special "letter" is sent at stream start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark That is not bulletproof, but the chances of AnsiString to have that for 1st and 2nd characters is pretty low - though still possible.
- You may make convention, that 1st two bytes would be Windows codepage and then use TEncoding to further convert bytes to string. That however would make future interaction with non-Windows system rather hard.
- You may pass [internet-standard encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML) as a AnsiString marker before the main load, like [it is done in URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). That marker would only use 7 bit ASCII values, so it would be safe to fetch it from stream. Yet there are a lot of synonyms in those charset names, so you'd have to query some dictionary with those synonymycal names.

Comment: not a bulletproof validation is the goal, it's just for debugging.thanks for your time.

Comment: then you can post some constant ALWAYS and check if it went like "ABCD" or "A"#0"B"#0"C"#0"D"#0 - however just like BOM, it would require modifying of the program

Comment: I completly rewrote the question,see above.It was misleading.